# Transfer Byte Array between C++ client/server in TIBCO DataSynapse GridServer

Tags: c++, tibco

First, thanks for stopping by and reading this post.

I have a situation where I have a client and a server in `C++`. I want to transfer binary data between client/server.

What is the best data type supported by `TIBCO DataSynapse GridServer` for this situation?

One possible solution in my opinion could be using `C++ string` in which case it could contain `null terminating` characters inside.  But the question is whether it is guaranteed that `GridServer` won't drop part of my message because of null terminating characters?

Regards,

Vlad.

Comment: A `std::string` can contain embedded zeroes (the null terminator) as long as you set the length correctly,. But why not a `std::vector<std:::byte>` (or `std::vector<std::uint8_t>`) instead?

Comment: I am not aware of any other datatype aside `string` accepted by `TIBCO DataSynapse GridServer` side.  The problem is that most libs working with strings consider zeros as the end of a string, now I just want to make sure that it is not the case with `TIBCO DataSynapse GridServer`

Comment: So its API explicitly only want a `std::string` object (or reference to one)? Or when you say "string" do you perhaps mean e.g. `char *` or similar? Then you can still use `std::vector<char>` internally yourself, and just pass a pointer to the first element of the vector (using e.g. its [`data`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/data) function).

Comment: The `Server API` accepts `std::string&`, now from client-side I send `std::string`(with 0s) with the correct size, I want to make sure that in the `middleware TIBCO code` (till the point it hits the `Server API` basically the code which I do not have control of) there is nothing which can affect my `std::string` because of `0s`.